# jQuery OR operator confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, operator-keyword

```
  <div id="my-nav-wrapper" class="noindex"> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Folder 0</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
</div> 

var jQmainmenu = $("#my-nav-wrapper ul");
var settings = {classname: "whatever"};
alert("Before: " + jQmainmenu.parent().get(0).className);    
jQmainmenu.parent().get(0).className  += settings.classname || "ddsmoothmenu";
alert("After: " + jQmainmenu.parent().get(0).className);
```

What I am trying to do is if classname property of `settings` dynamic object is null/falsey, the class name 'ddsmoothmenu' needs to be `apended` to the existing else whatever the settings.classname value.

```
 jQmainmenu.parent().get(0).className  += settings.classname || "ddsmoothmenu";
```

is this statement a valid statement? It seems to work, but I just wanted to make sure it is ok to use such syntax?

I know I can do assignment like below:

```
jQmainmenu.parent().get(0).className  = settings.classname || "ddsmoothmenu";
```

Which is syntactically correct, but is not what i wanted as it essentially `replaces` an existing class value on the element.

Comment: Have you looked into the jQuery `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`, and `.hasClass()` methods?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library it doesn't have operators.

Comment: I have and I know they are available for me to use, but this is for an older plugin that someone wrote, i just want to modify the plugin to append class name instead of replacing.

Comment: If you append the name to the raw class name string, you have to make sure you add a space character. It's really not the best way of doing things.

Comment: @Pointy Show me how you would do it differently??

Comment: I don't know what's going on in your application - I just know what good and bad practices are. For example, using the "emptiness" of the `.className` property as an indication of something is a fragile coding practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
jQmainmenu.parent().addClass(settings.classname || "ddsmoothmenu");
```

And jQuery will take care of all the quirks with browsers (for example not all IE versions will respect updates to className directly)